# GraphQL API with backend built in node js consuming high CPU Usage

Tags: node.js, graphql, apollo-server

We have built a graphql API , with our services written in node.js and leveraging apollo server. We are experiencing high CPU usage whenever requests per sec reach 20. We did profiling with flamegraphs and node built in profiler. Attaching the result of the built in profiler:-

```
[Summary]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  87809   32.1%   95.8%  JavaScript
      0    0.0%    0.0%  C++
  32531   11.9%   35.5%  GC
  182061   66.5%          Shared libraries
   3878    1.4%          Unaccounted

[Shared libraries]:
   ticks  total  nonlib   name
  138326   50.5%          /usr/bin/node
  30023   11.0%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc-2.27.so
  12466    4.6%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread-2.27.so
    627    0.2%          [vdso]
    567    0.2%          /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libstdc++.so.6.0.25
     52    0.0%          /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libm-2.27.so
```

Results from flamegraph also complement the above result that we didn't see any javascript function consuming high CPU.

Why /usr/bin/node is consuming so much CPU? has it something to do with the way code has been written or it is in general the trend?

Also to give little info about what our graphQL API Does:- upon receiving a request, depending on the request it makes 3 to 5 downstream API calls and doesn't do any CPU intensive work on it's own.

Versions:- 
Node version:- 10.16.3
graphql-modules/core:-  0.7.7
apollo-datasource-rest:- 0.5.0
apollo-server-express:- 2.6.8

A help is really appreciated here.

Comment: well, it all depends on how CPU intensive your resolvers are.

Comment: I'm encountering this problem too, is there any solution?

Comment: We used node js clustering technique to improve our performance.